# Without attractive forces, why would there be only ideal gases?

Tags: physical-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

I've read this statement in several places. What is the importance of attractive forces for solids and liquids?

Comment: The importance of attractive forces in solids and liquids is that you exist as a human being made of flesh, bones and liquid. Otherwise, if intermolecular attractive forces did not exist, we could not have existed in the human form. Everything would have existed as a gas.

Comment: Attractive forces is the reason why solids and liquids, and real gases exists. Else everything is fundamentally, collection of atoms.

Comment: The title is omitting the other attribute of ideal gasses - negligible molecular volume. So even without attractive forces, gases would not be ideal yet.

Comment: Not having Intermolecular forces would have far reaching impacts beyond the scope of the field of chemistry alone.

Answer (score 2):

**If there were no attractive forces solids and liquids would not exist**

The very existence of liquids and solids depends on attractive forces. two molecules that don't attract will *never* form a liquid or a solid. Liquids and solids only form because, under certain conditions of temperature and pressure, the attractive forces between their constituent molecules is strong enough to overcome the thermal energy trying to shake them apart.

A truly ideal gas has no attractive forces between the molecules and the molecules have no volume. Real near-ideal gases have negligible molecular volumes and attractive forces insignificant compared to thermal energy at that temperature and pressure. So, in the absence of any attractive forces, *everything* would be something close to an ideal gas unless compressed enough for the molecular size to become a factor in determining the volume of the gas (which is usually at extreme pressures).